# knitr spin with loop and comparison statements

Tags: r, comments, knitr

I've got a problem where I have an R script similar to that shown below (with a few loops to draw some graphs and multiple nested if statements to determine which set of graphs to draw, but this example will suffice.)

When `spin('spin-script.R')` is run, all of the `#'` comments within the if statements do not show on the final document.

Any insight as to why this happens would be greatly appreciated.

```
        opts_chunk$set(echo=FALSE)

#+ Title
print("This is the title")

#+ Choose, echo = FALSE
choices <-c("0","1", "2", "3", "4", "5")
choice  <- select.list(choices, title = "Pick your favourite Number")
numbers <- as.double(choices)
choice  <- numbers[choices==choice]


#+ SillyNumber
if(choice != 0){

    #+ Loop
    x <- 0
    for (i in 1:choice){

        #' Some text to show user
        x <- x + rnorm(1, choice, 1/choice)

        #+ IfStatement, echo = TRUE
        if( choice == 3  ) {

            #' That's my favourite number too
            {{cat("\n")}}
            #' Have a bonus boost 
            x <- 2 * x
        }
    }
}


# Display, echo = TRUE

sprintf("Your favourite number scored a total of %f points", x)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `doc` argument controls which lines are interpreted as documentation, and the default value  `"^#+'[ ]?"` only matches lines that begin with a `#` and no spaces before it. You probably want to set it to `spin(... , doc="^\\s*#+'[ ]?")` to allow white space before the `#'` string.  See `?spin` for details.

Alternatively you could document your code like this:

```
#+ SillyNumber
if(choice != 0){

    #+ Loop
    x <- 0
    for (i in 1:choice){

#'         Some text to show user
        x <- x + rnorm(1, choice, 1/choice)

        #+ IfStatement, echo = TRUE
        if( choice == 3  ) {

#'             That's my favourite number too
            {{cat("\n")}}
#'             Have a bonus boost 
            x <- 2 * x
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That now gives me this error :/ `Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src) : 
  <text>:6:0: unexpected end of input
4:     x <- 0
5:     for (i in 1:choice){
  ^`

Comment: I'm assuming this error is due to the fact the there will be 'overlapping' chunks. I've just had a quick google, but havent found anything related to this type of error yet

Comment: Hmmm. Are you sure this isn't an ordinary syntax error?  You could try adding an explicit line ending to the `doc` argument (e.g. `"^\\s*#+'[ ]?$"`), but i'm not sure that's the problem. (sorry, i'm not at my development machine at the moment).

Comment: Yeah, I've given it a try - it doesn't seem to work. Thanks so much for you input though! I'll continue battling and let you know if I can work anything out.

Answer (score 0):

Just reason, no solution here. I tried the above solutions, and got similar error like:
" Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src) : 
  :7:0: unexpected end of input"

Then I checked the corresponding Rmd file generated, find that the #' comments ("Train the model") break the for loop. This is why unexpected input.

```{r }

for (k in 1:fold_num){

#other code

```

Train the model

```{r }

# other code

}